# Parametric equations; two objects intersects

Tags: parametric

Two objects move through the air. The movement of the first can be described by the equation $(4t, 6+3t)$, the second by $(20-70(t-2)\cos u, 70(t-2)\sin u)$, where the parameter $t$ represents time and $u$ is the angle between the ground and the second objects direction.

How do you solve this? I tried cancelling $u$ by $\sin^2 u+\cos^2 u = 1$, but I dont think I get a reasonable answer...

Comment: *"I don't think I get a reasonable answer"* ... Show your answer and we can help you decide if it's reasonable. Please also show the work that led to the answer, so that people don't waste time (theirs or yours) duplicating your effort or explaining notions you already understand.

Comment: So just to clarify: The objects are supposed to collide?

Comment: I got really messy solution, that I don't think is correct. It would just be really tedious to write it out, what I did was that I gathered sin and cos on one side of each equation, raised to sin^2 and cos^2 and added the equations (so that I got 1 instead of sin^2+cos^2).

Comment: Yeah they are meant to collide.

Comment: I got the second degree polynomial equation (20 - 4t)^2 + (6 + 3t)^2 = ((70(t - 2))^2... but I believe it to be an error.

Comment: I'm sorry... it was correct after all, I just mixed positive and negative numbers in the calculations... sorry for wasting your time. =(